# jQuery.remove() and array.splice() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a page where there's an item list and a shopping list. If you add an x number of items from the items list to the shopping list, then try to remove them one by one, by clicking on the items from the shopping list and hitting delete on the modal that opens it works - the first time. Now here's the problem, if you try doing that all over again, for example adding another set of x number items to the shopping list and try to remove them one by one again. As soon as you hit the delete button on the modal I get unpredictable results, it either removes ALL the shopping list items, or 2 or 3 along with the item you're supposed to delete.

It's a simple jQuery.remove() and array.splice yet I can't get it to work. Apparently it's more complicated than I thought, and I've tried doing it a bunch of different ways.

Here's the page:
http://bigbiz.io/pos/

Thanks in advance!

Refactoring the code

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. Please be specific and share the code you tried

Comment: Your descripton "If you use just exec, the command will not be executed." is too broad. What is your output of the main script, etc? What does it mean in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. The "delete" button inside the modal is being triggered multiple times as I included it inside bootstraps "on show" script. Moving the button script outside of it was the solution.